# Cannot read property 'querySelectorAll' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

[image]

I receive this error on console Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelectorAll' of undefined ionic.bundle.js:2800 when i go from other view using ionic, but I don't know that is means, and how to solve it

Comment: it means that something is `undefined` and isn't expected to be - what part of your code triggers this error (some `container` is undefined) - an image of the error message is not required - there's something wrong with *your code*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disclaimer: I do not have much experience with ionic, this is based upon my experience with general JavaScript.

What your error likely comes from is that a specific element that the code relies on, which can't be found when you switch views. I gathered this from [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) being a property of an Element. It is used to get an child element by the provided [CSS Selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp). It is frequently used as `document.querySelectorAll` to get any element on the page that matches the query.

From what you're given us, it appears that your code(or the library internally) is trying to use `querySelectorAll` on an element in a specific view every time the view changes, regardless of whether it's the view that contains the element or not. This inevitably resulting in the specific element being `undefined`, and hence not having the `querySelectorAll` property. Here's some mock code that'd result in roughly the same problem as you have.

```
# This would be run every time the view changes. 
let myElement = document.querySelectorAll('#element-in-different-view');
myElement === undefined; // true

myElement.querySelectorAll('#foo');
// undefined is not an Element, and as such doesn't have the property `querySelectorAll`
```

> **Important Note:** As a community, we can provide you with more specific answers if you include the full traceback you get and a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).